# File b'train.csv' does not exist even though file exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, tensorflow

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-05c7c432b69f> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
    ----> 3 train_df = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    707                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    708 
    --> 709         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    710 
    711     parser_f.__name__ = name

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    447 
    448     # Create the parser.
    --> 449     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    450 
    451     if chunksize or iterator:

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    816             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    817 
    --> 818         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    819 
    820     def close(self):

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    1047     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    1048         if engine == 'c':
    -> 1049             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    1050         else:
    1051             if engine == 'python':

    /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
    1693         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
    1694 
    -> 1695         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
    1696 
    1697         # XXX

    pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

    pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in      pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: File b'../input/train.csv' does not exist
```

Please help! I tried using `pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")` but there is still an error. I am a Mac user using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: where is your `train.csv` give the `absolute path to it`

Comment: jupyter notebook by default will look into its own folder. If your "train.csv" is somewhere else, you have to give it absolute path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Are you sure you have the correct path?

`train_df = pd.read_csv("./input/train.csv")` 
(if the csv file is in the input folder which is in the same folder as your jupyter notebook)

Easiest would be you have a folder which contains the juptyer notebook and the csv file. Then you would just need to do:

`train_df = pd.read_csv("./train.csv")`  or
 `train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")`

2. Try using 
    `train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv",encoding='utf-8' )`

to get rid of the 'b in front of b'../input/train.csv'

Comment: Thankyou so much Julia It works. I just need to put the csv file in the same folder as jupyter notebook

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using an absolute path like this. The r at the beginning of the line helps to read the whole string as a raw string as it is, so when r is used, you don't have to worry about escaping slashes

```
import pandas

myFile = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\samarnat\Documents\Personal Docs\Projects\train.csv",encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced exact problem yesterday, following points helped me to resolve the problem

1. No combination filePath was working out for me.
2. I manually added full path to file and it worked for me.

So now I have added single line of code to my code and it works all the time regardless of folder structure. *Providing absolute path of file is the key*.

```
csv_file_abs = os.path.abspath(csv_file)
print(f'ABS PATH: {csv_file_abs}')
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_abs)
```

I hope this will help, please share your thoughts if this problem can be solved in other ways, this was quick-fix.

Comment: Excellent Generic approach. Its always safe to also check the current working directory using  os.getcwd(). [ensure to import os]. I had the issue when I copied my jupyter notebook to some other directory. But internally it was still pointing to my old directory path.  os.getcwd() helped to determine the right cwd and then your  os.path.abspath(csv_file) ensured to have a fool proof solution.

Answer (score 2):

Possible Reasons:

1. Path entered is incorrect or multiple folders of same name.
2. The name of the file is incorrect.
3. The file extension is not `csv`, it maybe `xlsx` (Rare chance)

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is also a " ` " mark on import line and the line below it.
Kindly check that also

Answer (score 1):

Try to give an absolute path of the file rather than giving a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

I found, if you are using a new version of Excel extension, you will face the problem.
First of all save the file eg.

1. save as fileName = test
2. below name section select

   - CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited )(*.csv)

now use Jupyter

```py
import pandas as pd
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for <strike>empty spaces</strike> space characters at the beginning or end of your file string.

Comment: What is an "empty space"? If a space character is present, then it's not "empty". If it empty, then it's not in the string.

Answer (score 0):

find out the directory you're working with using !pwd. Then upload the dataset in the same place. Then copy and paste the path of the directory in pd.read_csv command

```
    > df=pd.read_csv('/home/jovyan/demo/melb_data.csv')
```

what you're missing in the address is probably the [jovyan](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/what-is-with-the-weird-jovyan-user/1673) term

Answer (score -1):

if your text or csv file is in same folder where your jupyter notebook then instead of writing pd.read_csv('test.csv') write as pd.read_csv("test") bcz if your csv file explicitly shows .csv extension then only first way work or else second way.
for example if your file name looks like "test" then use pd.read_csv('test')
            or else filename is "test.csv" then use pd.read_csv('test.csv')
It depend on saving name of file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This answer is hard to understand. Please take the time to use correct punctuation and proper sentences.